Overlay Image Date to Landsat Images from a collection
I am trying to extract the date of capture from a range of Landsat images on Google Earth Engine, then overlay that date onto each resepctive image before exporting the image series as a timeline. Below is my current code, which exports the video only, without the associated date written to each individual image.
    var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_TOA')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 171))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 83))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10))
  .filterDate('1991-01-01','2011-12-30')
  .map(function(image) {
     var brightened = image.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']).add(1500);
    return brightened.visualize({
      bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
      min: 0,
      max: 30000
    });

 // Get the image date as text.
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');

    // Add the date as a text overlay.
    var textImage = text.draw({
      text: date,
      position: 'bottom-left',
      fontSize: 16,
      fontColor: 'white',
      outlineColor: 'black',
      outlineWidth: 2
    });

    // Combine the two images.
    return ee.ImageCollection([visualized, textImage]).mosaic();
  });

// Define an area to export.
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-123.0, 37.0, -121.0, 38.5]);

// Export (change dimensions or scale for higher quality).
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: collection,
  description: 'VideoExample',
  dimensions: 1080,
  framesPerSecond: 2,
  region: polygon,
});```


Unfortunately, Google Earth Engine (GEE) does not support native annotations for maps, videos, or images directly. However, you can utilize third-party packages to achieve this functionality. For example, you might find the package discussed in this GIS Stack Exchange Q&A helpful: Adding Timeline tool to Time Lapse in Google Earth Engine.
